# NodeJS (ExpressJS) Unhandled rejection TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, angular, express

I've been learning to use **Angular 6** and **NodeJS** (with **ExpressJS**) these past few days. To do this, I decided to create a front-end with **Angular 6** (o which theres a form) with the intention of passing information back and forth to my **PHPMyAdmin** database via the use of an API I created with **NodeJS**.
As you may have seen from the title, I get the following error when I try to submit my forms information:

> "*Unhandled rejection TypeError: callback is not a function*"

The code I used for the post action was taken from another functioning and similar API, the database receives the question_id and user_id but will not register the questions answers (which is the end goal).
Without furthur ado, here is the code to get and post:

```
const config = require('../config/config');
const knex      = config.db.knex;
const async     = require('async');


class TestModel {        
  getQuestions(callback) {
        knex('question')
        .select('id', 'libelle')
    .orderBy('id', 'asc')
        .then((data) => {
            callback(data);
        });
    }


  addResponse(reponse, callback) {
      knex('reponse')
      .insert({
          id_user : 1,
          id_question : reponse.id,
          libelle: reponse.answer,
      }).then((data) => {
          callback(data);
        });
  }        
}


module.exports = new TestModel();
```

Here is the rest:

```
app.post('/quiz', function(req, res, next){
    var answers = req.body;

    console.log(answers)

    for(var i = 0; i<answers.length; i++)
        {
            var obj = answers[i];
            Test.addResponse((obj,result) => {

            });                
        }        
    res.json({reponseserveur:'True'});    
});
```

Just for reference, "reponse" means response and "libelle" means label.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Syntax is

```
        Test.addResponse(obj, (result) => {

        });
```

it's working:

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Test.addResponse((obj,result) => {})
```

Looks like you're giving your callback as the first parameter (instead of `response`). It should be 2nd.

You probably wanted to do:

```
Test.addResponse(res, (obj,result) => {})
```